# django two Model filter

Tags: python, django, orm

I have to two Model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2=models.CharField(max_length=50)
class ModelB(model.Model):
    field3=models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    field4=Models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to get ModelA not in ModelB for modelA queryset result? How do it? Thinks!

Answer (score 2):

```
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__isnull=True)
```

Should work.

Comment: does this actually run on the table itself since in the ORM ModelA doesn't have reference to ModelB. Not argumentative, just wondering.

Comment: Under the hood, Django will do a left outer join. You can see the sql query by doing `print ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__isnull=True).query`